# Is it supported to create an integrated notebookVM when the workspace is configured to be in a VNET?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, azure-machine-learning-service, vnet

Trying to follow doc at [secure your experiments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/service/how-to-enable-virtual-network#use-a-machine-learning-compute) but after configuring default workspace storage for VNET access,  attempts to create integrated notebook VM fails with what looks like a storage access error.

Create Failed: 
Failed to clone samples. Error details: Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage This request is not authorized to perform this operation.

thanks,
jim

Answer (score 0):

We are working on adding virtual network support to NotebookVM.

Thanks